# Use the HoverTool in BokehJS

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, bokeh

I wrote some javascript to create a correlation plot in BokehJS (everything happens in the client, I can't use the Python Bokeh package).

Now, I would like to add a HoverTool to display tooltips when the user hovers over the squares, but I can't find documentation or examples on how to do this. I started looking at the coffeescript source and found [relavant pieces](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/b47193ce7e048dea4fe4a5f630f59e8d4907a17c/bokehjs/src/coffee/tool/inspectors/hover_tool.coffee), but I don't really understand how to integrate them.

Any help finding documentation or examples about how to use the HoverTool in pure BokehJS would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure javascript version that works with Bokeh 0.12.4.
It shows how to use grid plot, with separate hovers over each set of data.
The {0.01} in the hover object is used to format the values to 2 decimal places.

```js
var plt = Bokeh.Plotting;

var colors = [
  '#ee82ee', '#523ebf', '#9bc500', '#ffb600', '#f50019', '#511150',
  '#8b38fa', '#2e792a', '#ffef00', '#ff7400', '#a90064', '#000000'
]

function circlePlots(xyDict, plot_width, plot_height, title) {
  // make the plot and add some tools
  var tools = "pan,crosshair,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset";
  var p = plt.figure({
    title: title,
    plot_width: plot_width,
    plot_height: plot_height,
    tools: tools
  });

  // call the circle glyph method to add some circle glyphs
  var renderers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i += 1) {
    // create a data source
    var thisDict = {
      'x': xyDict['x'],
      'y': xyDict['y'][i],
      'color': xyDict['color'][i]
    }
    var source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
      data: thisDict
    });
    var r = p.circle({
      field: "x"
    }, {
      field: 'y'
    }, {
      source: source,
      fill_color: colors[i],
      fill_alpha: 0.6,
      radius: 0.2 + 0.05 * i,
      line_color: null
    });
    renderers.push(r);
  }
  var tooltip = ("<div>x: @x{0.01}</div>" +
    "<div>y: @y{0.01}</div>" +
    "<div>color: @color</div>");
  var hover = new Bokeh.HoverTool({
    renderers: renderers,
    tooltips: tooltip
  });
  p.add_tools(hover);
  return p
}

var pageWidth = 450;
var plotCols = 2;
var plots = [];
var plotWidth = Math.floor(pageWidth / plotCols)
if (plotWidth > 600) {
  plotWidth = 600
}
var plotHeight = Math.floor(0.85 * plotWidth)
for (var i = 0; i < plotCols; i += 1) {
  // set up some data
  var M = 20;
  var xyDict = {
    y: [],
    color: []
  };
  for (var j = 0; j <= 4; j += 1) {
    xyDict['x'] = [];
    xyDict['y'].push([]);
    xyDict['color'].push([]);
    for (var x = 0; x <= M; x += 0.5) {
      xyDict['x'].push(x);
      xyDict['y'][j].push(Math.sin(x) * (j + 1) * (i + 1));
      xyDict['color'][j].push(colors[j]);
    }
  }
  var title = "Sin(x) Plot " + (i + 1).toString();
  var p = circlePlots(xyDict, plotWidth, plotHeight, title);
  plots.push(p)
};
plt.show(plt.gridplot([plots], sizing_mode = "stretch_both"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First to use hover in bokeh you must add it as a tool and then personalise it to show what will be shown on hover. Look at this [US Unemployment example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/unemployment.html) from the bokeh docs

```
TOOLS = "hover,save"

p = figure(title="US Unemployment (1948 - 2013)",
    x_range=years, y_range=list(reversed(months)),
    x_axis_location="above", plot_width=900, plot_height=400,
    toolbar_location="left", tools=TOOLS)

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = OrderedDict([
    ('date', '@month @year'),
    ('rate', '@rate'),
])
```

Comment: also look at this link entitled 'callbacks for hover' http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#callbacks-for-hover

Comment: I saw those examples for the Python package, but I still don't know how to do this directly on the client (JavaScript) side. For my application, I need to do this in the browser so using the Python package is unfortunately not an option.